# Why does my Redis key show up only minutes after being stored?

Tags: heroku, redis, aws-lambda

I have a handler function on AWS Lambda that is connecting to a Redis instance to store a single key in the cache. The function has completed successfully but the key in Redis shows up minutes (or more) after the fact.

This behavior is observable on both [Heroku Redis](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis) and [Redis Cloud](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud), they're both hosted solutions.

I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing this lag. My Redis knowledge is practically zero, I know how to store a list using `LPUSH` and how to trim that list using `LTRIM`.

The writer to Redis uses [this Node client](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) while I observe the lag using `redis-cli` on my local machine.

**Is it common to experience this kind of lack in the setup I describe? What can I do to debug this?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm purposefully ignoring most of the information in the question and would like to refer only to the alleged symptom, namely that

> key show up only minutes after being stored

This behavior is impossible with Redis - any change to the data is **immediately** visible given Redis' design. That said, the only scenario what you're describing could be remotely possible is when you're writing to a Redis master server and reading from a very-badly-lagged slave. I can ensure you that this is not the case with Redis Cloud however.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason is due to the fact that the Lambda container starts to sleep as soon as your function terminates, and the Redis client you are using is all asynchronous APIs.

> Note that the API is entire asynchronous. To get data back from the server, you'll need to use a callback.

I'm assuming that the asynchronous SET is the last action performed in your Lambda function. Once that is called, the underlying Lambda container goes to sleep, and most likely, the actual SET action hasn't finished its job yet. Therefore, the record will not show in Redis until *the exact same Lambda container* was called to execute your function again, and finished the job that it was supposed to finish on the last execution. This is probably the *lag* that you are experiencing.

To test whether or not this is true, do a sleep action for a couple of seconds at the end of your function to delay the Lambda container going to sleep immediately, and see if the *lag* is still there.

I would also recommend not to use asynchronous behaviour APIs inside Lambda functions. They'll add state to your Lambda computation, and this is actually not recommended by AWS themselves within the Lambda documentations too.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a reasonable advise, not to use async api in Node Lambda - everything is async in Node, all the api are async. Can you give a link to this recommendation of AWS where it says not to use asynchronous behaviour APIs? In Lambda you have the context object with methods like done, succeed, fail which can be called from anywhere, including a callback and only then the container will stop http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model.html

Comment: Your explanation (the container going to sleep and, when resuming on the next invokation, resuming operation) sounds reasonable. However, your assumption to avoid asynchronous behavior, does not. It would mean you cannot reach any endpoint (e.g. other AWS services) because they all have some latency. Lambda would be completely unusable without this.